How to restore the original text when language is set back to English
I use google translation on a system showing name of recipes originally in English but some recipes use part of their names in French, for instance "Soup du jour" or "Cop au vin with noodles".
If a user changes the language to German for instance and then goes back to English evenything is translated back in English so my "Soup du jour" is now called "Soup of the day"
Is there a call to return to the original text?
A work around is to suppress the googtrand cookie and refresh the page but the refresh is really not user friendly. Does Google has a method for this?
